# development settings through adb shell

Tags: android, bash, android-intent, android-activity

is there some way to enable **OEM Unlocking through adb shell**?

First, I tried to start an activity but any of this paths I can not open:

`com.android.settings/.SubSettings` or `com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings`

This is the outcome:

```
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent {
 act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
 cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
 flg=0x10000000 
 pkg=com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings 
}
```

Comment: I'm searching the answer for another activity. But at least I can point you to a first step: `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings` launches the developer settings.